# How to not break, but restart the while True statement

Tags: python

ok so i was coding the "hangman" game on python and I basically want to know how to tell what position in the word the letter is in, and then ask the question what letter do I choose again. Instead it keeps spamming the position of the letter that it is in the word. Any help?

```
while True:
    for i in range(0, len(word)):
             if word[i] == guess and i > 2:

       print("Your letter is " + str(i + 1) + "th" + "!")

    elif word[i] == guess and i == 2:
                 print("Your letter is " + str(i + 1) + "rd" + "!")

             elif word[i] == guess and i == 1:
                 print("Your letter is " + str(i + 1) + "nd" + "!")

             elif word[i] == guess and i == 0:
                 print("Your letter is the " + str(i + 1) + "st" + "!") 

             guess = (str(input("Guess one letter!: ")))
```

Comment: Please correct your indentation, it's invalid.

Comment: You just corrected it lol

Comment: @CasualProgrammer This is not valid indentation, I don't think deceze touched the indentation, since it's unclear what blocks you want each statement to belong to

Comment: @awarrier99 Well it was fixed, happy now?

Comment: Where has it been fixed? Take a look at the code block showing in your post, there are inconsistent indents of 4, 6, 2, etc.

Comment: If this were JavaScript or anything I wouldn't make a big deal of it but since it matters so much in Python, it's unclear what indentation levels you intended for certain statements to be it, therefore making it hard to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know what youre base programm was, your code gives out lots of indent problems when I copy-pasted it. I only moved the "guess" input to the begin and fixed the indentation. I think this is what you want (I added an example).

```
word = ["w","o","r","d"]
while True:
    guess = (str(input("Guess one letter!: ")))
    for i in range(0, len(word)):
        if word[i] == guess and i > 2:

           print("Your letter is " + str(i + 1) + "th" + "!")

        elif word[i] == guess and i == 2:
            print("Your letter is " + str(i + 1) + "rd" + "!")

        elif word[i] == guess and i == 1:
            print("Your letter is " + str(i + 1) + "nd" + "!")

        elif word[i] == guess and i == 0:
            print("Your letter is the " + str(i + 1) + "st" + "!")
```

Comment: Regarding guess variable. Input() always returns a string, it doesn't need to be cast to string.

Comment: You didn't really say what I wanted to hear, but you helped me. Putting the input inside the while True statement saved me so much bro thx